# Don't show "edition" in German bibliography

Tags: bibtex, german

How do I disable displaying the word "edition" in the bibliography? Here's a working minimal example of what I mean:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}
\cite{Braess2013}
\bibliographystyle{alpha} \bibliography{literatur}
\end{document}
```

And the corresponding entry within the BibTeX file "literatur.bib":

```
@BOOK{Braess2013,
  title = {Finite Elemente: Theorie, schnelle L{\"o}ser und Anwendungen in der
    Elastizit{\"a}tstheorie},
  publisher = {Springer Spektrum},
  year = {2013},
  author = {Braess, Dietrich},
  pages = {XVI, 369 S.},
  address = {Berlin},
  edition = {5. {\"u}berarb. Aufl.},
  isbn = {978-3-642-34796-2},
  keywords = {Finite element method}
}
```

This results in the following output at the end of the PDF file:,

**Literaturverzeichnis**

*[Bra13] Dietrich Braess. Finite Elemente: Theorie, schnelle Löser und Anwendungen
in der Elastizitätstheorie. Springer Spektrum, Berlin, 5. überarb. aufl. edition,
2013.*

Also: is there a way to protect capitalized letters (in the above example: **A**ufl.) other than inserting braces by hand?

Comment: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/HinweiseLitverzeichnisse/blob/master/Hinweise.md

Comment: The `editioin` field takes a numerical argument, rather an ordinal. It should just contain `5` and print to *5 edition*, which is correct, since `alpha` is an english style. You would be much better of using the mmodern biblatex.

Comment: For a start you could use `alphadin`, the german implementation of `alpha`.

Comment: @Johannes_B: What do you mean by using mmodern biblatex? I would really appreciate a working example of what would cause the desired effect.

Comment: You can click the link above, that would introduce the modern methods, including examples. To the problem at hand, use `alphadin`.

Comment: Thanks, good answer. Excuse my impatience with the link, I'm sort of in a hurry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply change the bibliography style from `alpha` to `alphadin`, you get:

[image]

I believe this is what you're looking for.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@BOOK{Braess2013,
  title = {Finite Elemente: Theorie, schnelle L{\"o}ser und Anwendungen in der
    Elastizit{\"a}tstheorie},
  publisher = {Springer Spektrum},
  year = {2013},
  author = {Braess, Dietrich},
  pages = {XVI, 369 S.},
  address = {Berlin},
  edition = {5. {\"u}berarb. Aufl.},
  isbn = {978-3-642-34796-2},
  keywords = {Finite element method}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}
\cite{Braess2013}
\bibliographystyle{alphadin}   % was: "alpha"
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

All this is automatic with `biblatex+\biber`: `biblatex` cooperates with `babel`, and `biber`, unlike `bibtex`, understands `utf8`, so you can type directly accented letters

Note the syntax is diferent than ordinary bibliographies: you declare the bibliographic file(s) in the preamble with `\addbibresource{myfile.bib}` (with the extension!), and write `\printbibliography` where you want it.

```
\documentclass[ngerman , 11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
@BOOK{Braess2013,
title = {Finite Elemente: Theorie, schnelle Löser und Anwendungen in der
Elastizitätstheorie},
publisher = {Springer Spektrum},
year = {2013},
author = {Braess, Dietrich},
pages = {XVI, 369 S.},
address = {Berlin},
edition = {5. überarb. Aufl.},
isbn = {978-3-642-34796-2},
keywords = {Finite element method}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{literatur.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{Braess2013}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]